# Trying Extract List of Categories with Corresponding Tickets using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I am trying to extract list of Categories with the corresponding Tickets for a specific userId using Linq Lambda expression.

Category:

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Ticket:

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

User

```
public class User 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I tried so far. But it is not even close.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetCategories(string userid)
        {
            var categories =  _context.Categories
                                            .Include(c => c.Tickets)
                                            .AsQueryable();
            

            categories = categories
                      .Where(c => c.Tickets.Any(t =>t.User.Id.Equals(id)));            

            return await categories.ToListAsync();
        }
```

How can I have a list of categories with corresponding tickets for a specific userId?

Comment: So what does it return, and what do you expect? Also don't repeat the same "*a list of categories with corresponding tickets*" be specific

Comment: I am expecting Categories with tickets those match the given Id with ticket userId

Comment: And what does that query give you?

Comment: This returns category and corresponding all tickets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219643/discussion-between-deep-and-thegeneral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line of code:

```cs
categories = categories.Where(c => c.Tickets.Any(t =>t.User.Id.Equals(id)));
```

This will return *all categories that contain at least 1 ticket with the specified user id*, but *all* tickets in the category will be included. My understanding is, you want to keep *only the tickets that belong to the specified user id*.

The fact that your `Ticket`s are represented by an `ICollection<Ticket>` instead of `IEnumerable<Ticket>`, make this a bit more difficult - since LINQ works on `IEnumerable`s. That's the reason for the `ToList()` call, which causes enumeration - something to be aware of here - `Ticket`s collection is *no longer lazy* past that point.

This code will do what you want:

```cs
IEnumerable<Category> selection = (from c in categories
                                    select new Category
                                    {
                                        Id = c.Id,
                                        CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                                        Tickets = (from t in c.Tickets
                                                    where t.User.Id.Equals(id)
                                                    select t).ToList()
                                    }).Where(c => c.Tickets.Count() > 0);
```

but, I think, both performance-wise and readability-wise, you might want a loop instead:

```cs
List<Category> selection = new List<Category>();
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    category.Tickets = category.Tickets.Where(t => t.User.Id.Equals(id)).ToList();

    if (category.Tickets.Count > 0)
    {
        selection.Add(category);
    }
}
```

Finally, since your `Ticket` class carries the `Category` info anyway, it may be worth to flatten the list using `SelectMany`:

```cs
var selection = categories.SelectMany(c => c.Tickets.Where(t => t.User.Id.Equals(id)));
```

This returns a *flattened list* of `Ticket`s - but only the ones that match the specified user id, from all categories. This has the advantage of staying lazy (it's still an `IEnumerable`), being simple, and very likely of higher performance than the other options; but, you no longer have the nested list.

Take your pick!

Comment: Great explanation.